# mysql evaluate function at specified integer values

Tags: mysql

How can I do somethig like this in MYSQL?

SELECT MyFunction(x) where x in (1,2,7,20,30);

Seems like a simple query should exist for this and in Oracle I can do it easily using the Dual table but I don't see a trick to do this in MySQL.  NOTE that in my case 1,2,7,20,30  do NOT come from a table (in that cast it would be easy, just a simple join).  In my situation I will be generating the query ( in particular the integer values) in C# and then making the DB Call.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example output would help but maybe something like this....

```
Select myFunction(X)
FROM (Select 1 UNION Select 2 union select 7 union select 20 union select 30)\
```

Alternate:

--PSEUDO...

```
Select myFunction(X)
FROM (Generate Table containing values Min to max of range passing in) 
where Value in (your list);
```

Something like: [Select a sequence between two numbers on MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164573/select-a-sequence-between-two-numbers-on-mysql)

Comment: this works for me as in my immediate situation I will have max 10 integer values!  I guess there is no cleaner solution for larger sets say 50 values?  A way which avoids the somewhat clumsy "union select" repetition 50 times?

Comment: Since the values are provided and not pattern based, we can't loop to generate them.  the Clumsy union select is all I can think of here.... Unless... We know min max, then we could loop and generate a set say 1-1000 and then simply say where in... but I'm not sure that's any cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`union` is a way to do that.

```
SELECT (x + 100) 
FROM (select 1 as x union select 2 union select 7 union select 20 union select 30) t;
```

## Output:

```
mysql> SELECT (x + 100)
    -> FROM (select 1 as x union select 2 union select 7 union select 20 union select 30) t;
+-----------+
| (x + 100) |
+-----------+
|       101 |
|       102 |
|       107 |
|       120 |
|       130 |
+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```